# WlanConnect from wlanapi.dll in Windows XP fails

Tags: windows-xp, wlanapi

I am creating a program which will be able to connect automatically to a wireless network. For doing that, I am using a library called ManagedWifi, which uses the library "wlanapi.dll". When I try to use the code on Windows Vista, everything is fine, but when I use it on Windows XP it fails. I have checked that it has Service Pack 3 installed, and "wlanapi.dll" is located in Windows/system32. The problem is when ManagedWifi calls this method:

```
[DllImport("wlanapi.dll")]
    public static extern int WlanConnect(
        [In] IntPtr clientHandle,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid interfaceGuid,
        [In] ref WlanConnectionParameters connectionParameters,
        IntPtr pReserved);
```

It throws an error ***System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Element not found***. But, if the library is correctly located in system32, why does it throw this error? And why only in Windows XP and not in Vista?

Thank you very much to everyone

**EDIT:** I have checked boith file versions, Vista and XP, and I've seen they are different (XP: 5.1, Vista: 6.0) but I have copied Vista's version to XP and I still have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

The problem is that Windows XP, when the network is an adhoc network, adds the "-adhoc" sufix to the name. When I was trying to connect to it, it didn't find the "xxx" network

Comment: hi can you please share your full code ?

Answer (score 0):

Using :

```
[DllImport("wlanapi.dll")]
    internal static extern int WlanSetProfile(
        [In] IntPtr hClientHandle,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid interfaceGuid,
        [In] WlanProfileFlags dwFlags,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string strProfileXml,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string strAllUserProfileSecurity,
        [In] bool bOverwrite,
        [In, Out] IntPtr pReserved,
        [Out] out WlanReasonCode dwReasonCode
    );
```

You have to create the profile first, Element not found says that the profile which you are trying to connect is not available